# I need help understanding what Animated.diffClamp(value, min, max) is expected to do

Tags: react-native

While researching  sticky headers, I encountered diffClamp for the first time, I have tried to use the API to understand better what the function does, however comments associated with it in react-native's documentation and articles I found while researching have made it very confusing what behavior to expect. My observations were that the function does keep the value between the min and max, while returning the closest value from either the min or max otherwise. Please, anyone with better understanding should kindly confirm or rebut, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand someone may be having the same difficulty I had understanding Animated.diffClamp, hence this follow-up. I learnt that it keeps track of all input values that gets passed into the function, upon every call, it takes the difference between successive inputs and clamps the result between the min and max values. In such a case where it has no previous input value(i.e the first call of the function), it clamps the input value between the min and max and returns the result.